# Not getting the "MESSAGE_DELIVERED" Firebase event

Tags: android, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging, latency

I am trying to measure the latency between having a message exit Firebase Servers and being received on an Android app via the Firebase SDK. I have BigQuery integrated with my Firebase project, and have tried adding the following code:

```
// In the manifest:
<meta-data android:name= "delivery_metrics_exported_to_big_query_enabled"
        android:value="true"/>

// In my Application object:
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery(true);
```

The code seems to be exporting data to BigQuery. However, to calculate what I want I need timestamps for two different types of events associated to the same message id, "MESSAGE_ACCEPTED" and "MESSAGE_DELIVERED". Then, all I have to do is run a simple query that calculates the timestamp difference between those two.

My problem is: I can **never** seem to get the "MESSAGE_DELIVERED" variant for a given message id. I only ever get the "MESSAGE_ACCEPTED" side of the equation.

I am sending messages to the Android device via my own JavaScript app, and the request I make is like so:

```
app.get('/triggerAnt', function(req, res){
  axios.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
      to:<TOKEN_FOR_DEVICE_GOES_HERE>,
      notification:{
        "title":"TESTNOTIFICATIONLATENCY",
        "body":"TESTINGLATENCY"
      },
      fcm_options: {
        analytics_label:<LABEL_HERE>
      }
    }, {headers: headers})
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
})
```

I would like to point out that the notification does effectively reach the device and I can open it too.
Is this delay on BigQuery's side or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue ?